# How can I create own string compare object for C++ map

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

I need a map of key to regard `'-'` as `'1'` or `'0'`.

For example :

The `map<string, int>` already has an element `<"1-1", 1>`. When I use `map.find("101")`, I should get `<"1-1", 1>`.

This is my function

```
struct keycompare
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& x, const std::string& y)
    {
        int len = x.length();
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            if(x[i]==y[i])continue;
            else if( x[i]=='-'  || y[i]=='-')continue;
            else return x[i]<y[i];
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

It will go wrong in some cases when I use `map.find()`. Is there any good way to debug it?

Comment: Which case for example goes wrong?

Comment: One thing wrong is you need to make sure `i` is less than `x.length()` as well as `y.length()`.  You only check the for the former.

Comment: Do not write `else` when you use `continue` or `return`

Comment: If everything in the map is of the form `a-b`, why don't you convert the key you search for to the same format?  If everything in the map is not of form `a-b` then what is it?

Comment: I am sorry I did not say clearly. 
All the string just contain {1,0,-} and the length will be the same. 
And I will only use find() with string contains{1,0}. 
So the case map.find("11-") will not happen.

Comment: OK, so if the map contains `"10-"` and your search term is `"10"` just do `map.find(search_term + "-");`.  Does that solve your problem?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  Please use @PaulSanders in any response if you want to attract my attention.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use such a comparison with `std::map`.

One of the requirements of the `Compare` template member is the transitivity of the equivalence relation [`!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare). Your compare does not hold, e.g. in the case

```
keycompare comp;

auto equiv = [comp](auto l, auto r) { return !comp(l, r) && !comp(r, l); };

std::string a("111");
std::string b("1-1");
std::string c("101");

std::cout << std::boolalpha << "a == b " << equiv(a, b) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << "b == c " << equiv(b, c) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << "a == c " << equiv(a, c) << std::endl;
```

Specifically, if your map contains both "111" and "101", which should be found with a search for "1-1"?

Comment: I am sorry I did not say clearly. 
I will only find the string contains {1,0} . So the case map.find("1-1") will not happen. 
And all the string's length will be the same.

Comment: @ruby86123 that doesn't matter. `keycompare` is not a valid parameter for a `std::map`, and a conforming implementation is *not required* to inform you, because in the general case that would be an *impossible* requirement